# python function running more slowly after parallelization

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multiprocessing

I have a parallelized work flow in python using pool.map(). The workflow sends some data to the workers and uses numpy to perform several matrix operations, collect and return the results. When running the code in serial, the worker's internal computation takes 11 seconds. When parallelized, the worker's internal computation takes about 3 times as long. The timing starts after the data and processes have been forked and ends before the data are sent back to the parent process. The function looks like this:

```
def my_function(function_values):
    start_time
    process_data
    end_time
    return processed_data
```

I'm not referencing anything outside of `my_function`. Nearly all references on parallelization I've seen point to the time cost of serialization and de-serialization, but nothing about a function itself taking longer. What is causing the increase in processing time?

Comment: Some things to check: Does the parallelization even work e.g. are all CPU cores busy? Does it all fit in your RAM or has the system started to use the swap file?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, parallelization works on all CPU cores. I have an 8-core machine and I send tasks to only 6 cores at a time. And each process only consumes several hundred megabytes of RAM. Is an object running up against the GIL somehow?